# How to Sum of Custom datatype of int in SML?

Tags: sml, smlnj, custom-data-type

I'm new to SML and are playing with datatypes and such, I have this datatype for example:

```
datatype test = UInt of int
```

As far as I understand, UInt should work just like a normal int, but I cannot make it do simple things like sum 2 UInt:

```
val x = UInt(2)
val y = UInt(3)
val z = x + z
```

This code gives me this error:

```
= stdIn:4.11 Error: overloaded variable not defined at type
  symbol: +
  type: test
```

How can I make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `+` is defined for two types -- `int`s and `real`s, with type `int * int -> int` and `real * real -> real`, respectively. It is not defined for your type `test`.

You can redefine `+` to work on the `test` type as follows:

```
val (op+) = fn (UInt x, UInt y) => UInt (x + y)
```

However, redefining built-ins is generally not the best idea. You could also define a function that will take any `int * int -> int` function and give you a `test * test -> test` function that behaves as expected as follows:

```
fun lift f = fn (UInt x, UInt y) => UInt (f(x,y))
```

Using this method, you could define addition for your test type as `val liftedAdd = lift (op+)`, and use this sort of function for all of your work with the `test` type.

However, there isn't much good reason to create a datatype that is simply a wrapper for an already existing type with no additional information. You might be looking for the `type` keyword, which will define a new type to be equal to one that already exists.

For example, if you say:

```
type test = int
val x : test = 2
val y : test = 3
val z = x + y
```

The addition will work, because while both `x` and `y` are `test`s, and `+` is defined on `int`s, `test` is simply an alias for `int`.